# SQL Server Convert Rows to Columns

Tags: sql-server

Not sure if this is possible, have orders which can be linked to any number of contracts, Id like to display all contracts & values from the same orderno in one row. I've tried using a Pivot but I dont think I hav enough expereince with the Pivot to figure this out. Here is how the data is currently displayed:

```
OrderNo Contract Value
1       Con1    5000
1       Con2    10000
2       Con3    2000
3       Con4    500
3       Con5    2000
3       Con6    1000
```

This is how I'd like to display the data:

```
OrderNo  Contract    Value   Contract2   Value2  Contract3   Value3
1        Con1        5000    Con2        10000   NULL        NULL
2        Con3        2000    NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL
3        Con4        500     Con5        2000    Con6        1000
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How firm are you on your desired output?  The PIVOT function would yield column headers of, "Con1", "Con2" and "Con3", with values of `Value` under them.  In this example, you end up with 4 columns instead of 7.  Also, do you know how many different contracts there will be?  If there are only a handful, PIVOT will work fairly easily.  If there is any number of them, then you would need to use dynamic SQL to build a PIVOT statement.  And that could get really large, depending on your data.

Answer (score -1):

[Here is an article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/) that does a pretty good job of walking you through how to build a dynamic SQL pivot.  There are some things to keep in mind...  If the number of contracts that you need to include gets exceptionally large then your dynamic SQL statement may grow to be too large to fit into your varchar variable.  Also, performance might just be pretty bad.  So know your data and filter it as necessary.  But this should give you output that fairly closely looks like what you were asking for.  (If you require 2 columns of data per contract, then you'll have to get creative.  But I suspect that this will be sufficient.)

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this answer mind explaining why you felt this answer deserved a downvote?

Comment: Thanks for the replies folks, Happy St. Pat's!